# C++/CLI assembly loading FileNotFoundException

Tags: c++, .net, dll, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I am making a photoshop plug-in using C++/CLI. Some files in the project are compiled to native code, and one file is compiled to managed code. Because of that, I cannot add a reference to an assembly on project level, but rather on file level via `#using` statement.

I referenced `System.dll`, `Windows.dll`, `PresentationFramework.dll` and `WindowsBase.dll` successfully. (There are some issues with intellisense which doesn't want to load metadata, but compiles without errors. I solved the intellisense issue by stating full name of the assembly.)

However, I can not add a reference to my own non-framework assembly. When I load plug-in in Photoshop and debug it, I get following error>

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.*

*Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'ColorPickerControl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2317994184a7a708' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I tried to change target framework of my dll, to make assembly shared (public) - hence `PublicKeyToken` is not null -, to return other assemblies name to their short name (I changed them because intellisense was not loading metadata). Didn't work.

Any suggestions? It might be a problem with target framework, but I don't know what should be stated as a target framework. It's C++/CLI - no properties dialog like in C# where you can easily select target framework.

My code:

```
#using <System.dll>
#using <PresentationCore.dll>
#using <PresentationFramework.dll>
#using <WindowsBase.dll>


#using <C:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\ColorPickerControl.dll>


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Controls;
using namespace System::Windows::Media;
//using namespace ColorPickerControlNamespace;


char __cdecl fManaged2(const char* input)
{


    Window^ w = gcnew Window();
    Label^ l = gcnew Label();
    l->Content = "This works!";
    l->Background = Brushes::Orange;
    TextBox^ txt = gcnew TextBox();
    txt->Width = 300;
    txt->Height = 25;
    Grid^ g = gcnew Grid();
    g->Children->Add(l);
    g->Children->Add(txt);


    ColorPickerControlNamespace::ColorPickerControl^ c = gcnew ColorPickerControlNamespace::ColorPickerControl();


    w->Content = g;
    w->ShowDialog();

    Byte bb = Convert::ToByte(txt->Text);
    return bb;
}
```

Comment: See also [How to enable assembly bind failure logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)